# Is there Shell script date Format (dd month year time) (29 Oct 2013 05:26:30)

Tags: shell, date

I want the date format in shell script as (`dd month year time`)

Example:

```
29 Oct 2013 05:26:30
```

Please can anyone help me in solving this.

Comment: You mean with bash? did you try date --help ?

Comment: if i use date i am getting like this (Tue Oct 29 15:15:33 IST 2013) but i want in the format (29 Oct 2013 05:26:30)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$ date "+%d %b %Y %T"
29 Oct 2013 10:45:08
```

From [`man date`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date):

> **%d**     day of month (e.g., 01)
>
> **%b**     locale's abbreviated month name (e.g., Jan)
>
> **%Y**     year
>
> **%T**     time; same as %H:%M:%S

Comment: I see your time-zone. :D

Comment: Same as yours Kent ;)

Comment: We all moved to +1 UTC now :D